# What is difference between Event based and Time based Job scheduling in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, msbi

What is difference between Event based and Time based Job scheduling in SSIS?

I'm quite new to MSBI and SSIS,I did some search on this and found that usage of these depends 
of the requirements of the user now could somebody please guide me to understand the stuff related to this?

Answer (score 0):

Well Time Based scheduling takes place at a specific time or at determined intervals, and Event based would take place after a specific event has happened for example On login.